# Perl: How to assign a common value to undef elements in an array?

Tags: perl

I am building five arrays in perl like (null, null, 32, 54, null, 59). So I first put the values that I know at specific index and fill the others with null. I do this like this

```
my @p0_series, @p1_series;
$p0_series[2] = "test";
$p1_series[3] = "string";
$p2_series[2] = "hello";
$p3_series[2] = "hi";
for($a = 0; $a < 5; $a++) {
  if(!defined $p0_series[$a]) {
   $p0_series[$a] = null;
  }

  if(!defined $p1_series[$a]) {
   $p1_series[$a] = null;
  }

  if(!defined $p3_series[$a]) {
   $p3_series[$a] = null;
  }

  if(!defined $p4_series[$a]) {
   $p4_series[$a] = null;
  }

  if(!defined $p5_series[$a]) {
   $p5_series[$a] = null;
  }
}
```

I am trying to reduce this code to simpler one but I am not able to use the variable name p0_series, p1_seires dynamically in a loop. I tried like

```
for($a=0: $a <5; $a++ ){
if(!defined $p$i_series[$a] ) {
 #  assign values;
}
}
```

Which is not working.  I am new to perl any help is appreciated. 
Is it possible I can assign the null value to all the undef elements in the array in a simpler manner?

Comment: Tip: `use strict; use warnings` at the top of your script to get warned about some problems with your script which I didn't address in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl doesn't have `null`, but it has `undef` – which incidentally is the default value for unassigned elements in arrays:

```
my @array = (undef, undef, 32, 54, undef, 59);
```

creates the same structure as:

```
my @array;
$array[2] = 32;
$array[3] = 54;
$array[5] = 59;
```

There is no need to assign the other fields to `undef` yourself.

If you are trying to assign a default value to elements which are currently `undef`, you could write something like this (but note the limitations below):

```
defined or $_ = "default" for @array;
```

On Perl 5.10 or later, you can use the `//` defined-or operator:

```
$_ //= "default" for @array
```

To assign defaults for multiple arrays:

```
$_ //= "default" for @array, @other_array
```

If you want to set an array to a specific length, you can do `$#array = $length - 1`, so this actually specifies the highest index. This removes entries from longer arrays. For shorter arrays, the newly created entries will all be `undef`.

---

There is a small problem with this: Perl has two kinds of `undef`:

- Scalars can contain the value “undef” like `my $foo = undef`.

  This is the case if we initialize the whole array at once like `my @array = (undef, undef, 32, 54, undef, 59)`.
- Unassigned values in arrays or hashes *share* their `undef` scalar, which is read-only.

  This is the case when we initialize the array by assigning some indices only, like `$array[4] = 2`.

Usually this is no problem, but in a for-loop, the `$_` is an *alias* to the current scalar, which in our case can be readonly. Therefore we can't always do `$_ //= "default" for @array` but must either:

- Assign directly into the array element, which creates an assignable scalar in that slot:

  ```
  $array[$_] //= "default" for 0 .. $#array;
  ```

  For multiple arrays:

  ```
  for my $ref (\@array, \@other_array) {
    $ref->[$_] //= "default" for 0 .. $#$ref;
  }
  ```
- Don't assign to the element and create a copy of the array with defaults instead:

  ```
  @array = map { $_ // "default" } @array;
  ```

  For multiple arrays:

  ```
  @$_ = map { $_ // "default" } @$_ for \@array, \@other_array;
  ```

  While I perceive this as more elegant, there can be some problems with this as each array element is copied.

Comment: Awesome, great tip. My requirement is for undef elements I need to make it null. I have to feed this array elements to highcharts so null is required there. This is exactly I was searching for.

Comment: Hi,  I am using perl v5.10.1. I am able to change for single array but when I do if for multiple arrays I get the error "Modification of a read-only value attempted at - line " .

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8 Could you show the code that isn't working? You can only assign defaults for variables like `$_ = 1 for @array`, not for literals like `$_ = 1 for 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: my @test;
my @test2;
$test[3] = 'test';
$test2[2] = 'samp';
$_ //= 'a' for @test, @test2;

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8 Thank you, I updated with a definitive solution. This error was triggered by the way (a) how unassigned array values are represented and (b) how for-loops work. Very subtle stuff and *not* my favorite Perl feature.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the detailed explanation. Just one clarification I am not seeing a difference in $array[$_] //= "default" for 0 .. $#array; and @array = map { $_ // "default" } @array; In both cases the default value is assigned to the element. The reference of array also not changes .

Comment: @SpreeTheGr8 Aaand you're right again. Apparently in-place `map` gets optimized to avoid copies of each element.

Answer (score -2):

Agreed, but just incase in perl you can also create run-time variable name. As in your case

if(!defined $p$i_series[$a] )

if (!defined ${"p$i"."_series"}[$a] )

This should do the job and create the variable $p1_series[$a] , $p2_series[$a] and further on

Comment: -1: This is a horrible tip and recommends bad programming practices which obfuscate the code and make it less maintainable. Your “symbolic references” also only work with global variables, which are a problem themselves. I recommend you read [MJD's three-part series on the issue](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). His solution: Use a hash (of arrayrefs).